# yeoman grunt-wiredep not injecting dependencies

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-wiredep, wiredep

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task

Done, without errors

but not injecting dependencies of bower.json.
Cant debug this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Gruntfile.js:

```
wiredep: {

        target: {

            // Point to the files that should be updated when
            // you run `grunt wiredep`
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
            ],
            // Optional:
            // ---------
            options: {
                cwd: '',
                dependencies: true,
                devDependencies: false,
                exclude: [],
                fileTypes: {},
                ignorePath: '',
                overrides: {}
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 10):

Please verify a type of dependencies in bower.json file. You probably have them installed as devDependencies using **--save-dev**. Regarding to the optional section for wiredep (that You attached) **"devDependencies"** option is switched off, so this kind of dependencies are ommited. In order to check this case quickly turn on option as below and run wiredep task:

```
        // Optional:
        // ---------
        options: {
            // ...
            devDependencies: true
            // ...
        }
```

If my assumptions will confirm You should have dependencies injected in Your target html between tags:

```
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- place for dependencies -->
  <!-- endbower -->
```

Comment: was saving as devDependencies and wasted couple of hourse finding it :(. Thanks @dinel28